# How to split complex alignments into multiple columns?

Tags: environments, multicol, alignment, arrays, environment-variables

My document includes multiple recursive definitions. To increase readability, I split these definition into multiple (usually two) columns. To get more accurate alignments, I use array. Thus, multicols does not work. My current workaround looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\restrict}[1]{_{\geq #1}}

\begin{document}
  ...

  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.35 \textwidth}\vspace{0pt}%
    $\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l@{\;}c@{\;}l}%
      (& y \in Y&)\restrict{x} & = & y \in Y \\%
      (& y \leq z &)\restrict{x} & = & y \leq z \\%
      (& a(y) &)\restrict{x} & = & a(y) \\%
      (&\neg \mu &)\restrict{x} & = & \neg \mu \restrict{x}%
    \end{array}$
    \vspace{0pt}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.65 \textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
    $\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l@{\;}c@{\;}l}
      (&\mu \lor \nu &)\restrict{x} & = & \mu\restrict{x} \lor \nu\restrict{x}\\
      (&\exists y. \mu &)\restrict{x} & = & \exists y.( x \leq y \land \mu\restrict{x})\\
      (&\exists Y.\mu &)\restrict{x} & = & \exists Y.(\forall y. (y \in Y \rightarrow x \leq y) \land \mu\restrict{x})\\
    \end{array}$
  \end{minipage}\vspace{\baselineskip}

...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there an automated way, like multicols, to do this?
If not, how would one go about to write one. In particular, how can one evaluate the height of the textbody, before producing it. And based on that, how can one evaluate the respective width of the textbodys, to compute a relative width of the columns.
Where to start?

Edit: I want:

1. Columns of equations in my output
2. Controle over the spacing, and alignment in my alignment
3. Linear code (i.e. the corresponding next equation is in the next line of code)

Comment: it' s not entirely clear what your requirements are here, or why you need the minipages

Answer (score 2):

Columns of alignments like this are the main use case for `align`. Note unlike `array`, `align` uses display math, and requires much simpler markup a space around = and between the columns is automatic.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\restrict}[1]{_{\geq #1}}

\begin{document}
  ...

  \begin{align}
      ( y \in Y)\restrict{x} & =  y \in Y &
             (\mu \lor \nu )\restrict{x} & =  \mu\restrict{x} \lor \nu\restrict{x}\\
      ( y \leq z )\restrict{x} & =  y \leq z &
            (\exists y. \mu )\restrict{x} & =  \exists y.( x \leq y \land \mu\restrict{x})\\
      ( a(y) )\restrict{x} & =  a(y) &
             (\exists Y.\mu )\restrict{x} & =  \exists Y.(\forall y. (y \in Y \rightarrow x \leq y) \land \mu\restrict{x})\\
      (\neg \mu )\restrict{x} & =  \neg \mu \restrict{x}%
  \end{align}

...
\end{document}
```

If you really want to align the `(..)` so over-spacing the smaller terms, you could use `alignat*` rather than `align*`, but I wouldn't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Align and and Alignat are most likely better style anyways (though there are still example where I want more controle over the spaceing). However, I dislike the formatting needed to use align. I would like to have the linear order of my equations reflected in my code. Otherwise, it makes it much harder to change things later one. So, again I come back to my question, is there a solution like multicols for more complex alignments?

Comment: @grbll anything multcol-like would require equal width columns. But you can always do something, leave it unaccepted, and someone will post a column major answer, or I might later if no one else does. you could for example just have a list of terms then use expl3 list handling to re-order in pairs and construct the above answer

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution to my Problem is the following approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\restrict}[1]{_{\geq #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begingroup
  \allowdisplaybreaks
    \noindent
    \begin{align*}
          ( y \in Y)\restrict{x} & =  y \in Y \\%
          ( y \leq z )\restrict{x} & =  y \leq z \\%
          ( a(y) )\restrict{x} & =  a(y) \\%
          (\neg \mu )\restrict{x} & =  \neg \mu \restrict{x}\\
          (\mu \lor \nu )\restrict{x} & =  \mu\restrict{x} \lor \nu\restrict{x}\\
          (\exists y. \mu )\restrict{x} & =  \exists y.( x \leq y \land \mu\restrict{x})\\
          (\exists Y.\mu )\restrict{x} & =  \exists Y.(\forall y. (y \in Y \rightarrow x \leq y) \land \mu\restrict{x})\\
    \end{align*}

  \endgroup
  
\end{multicols}
  
\end{document}
```

It still lacks the power of array, but you can split alignments into multiple columns. And, later on, add a line, use more (or fewer) columns, or change the order, without changing every line in the alignment.